# Changing the columns to rows with rbind

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have a data-set as following:

```
     N2     N3     N4    N5     N7     N8    N10    N12   N13    N14   N17   N19    N25    N28   N29    N31    N32
1 1.300 -0.170 -0.344 2.138  0.684  0.656  0.882  0.684 1.822  1.214 2.046 2.432  0.208  0.312 0.530  0.358  0.264
2 0.888 -0.534 -0.684 1.442 -0.178 -0.060  0.430 -0.148 1.420  0.286 1.444 2.138 -0.264 -0.042 0.398 -0.196 -0.148
3 0.792 -0.564 -0.622 0.998 -0.320  1.858 -0.036 -0.118 1.476  0.110 0.964 2.048 -0.480 -0.434 0.040 -0.538 -0.322
4 0.324 -1.022 -1.128 1.380 -0.792  1.042 -0.054 -0.158 1.518 -0.102 1.354 2.386 -0.708 -0.510 0.258 -0.696 -0.566
5 0.650 -0.774 -0.982 1.124 -0.540  3.200 -0.052 -0.258 1.452  0.028 1.022 2.110 -0.714 -0.646 0.266 -0.768 -0.532
6 0.670 -0.660 -0.844 1.248 -0.550  2.868 -0.098 -0.240 1.380 -0.012 1.164 2.324 -0.498 -0.474 0.860 -0.588 -0.324
  MeteoSwiss
1       -0.6
2       -1.2
3       -1.0
4       -0.8
5       -0.4
6       -0.2
```

I would like to change the places of rows and columns.

I have used the rbind as following:

```
data <- data.frame(hour1=numeric(0),hour2=numeric(0),hour3=numeric(0),hour4=numeric(0),hour5=numeric(0),hour6=numeric(0),hour7=numeric(0),hour8=numeric(0),hour9=numeric(0),hour10=numeric(0),hour11=numeric(0),hour12=numeric(0),hour13=numeric(0),hour14=numeric(0),hour15=numeric(0),hour16=numeric(0),hour17=numeric(0),hour18=numeric(0),hour19=numeric(0),hour20=numeric(0),hour21=numeric(0),hour22=numeric(0),hour23=numeric(0),hour24=numeric(0))


data <- rbind(data[1,],data2)
data <- rbind(data[2,],data3)
data <- rbind(data[3,],data4)
data <- rbind(data[4,],data5)
data <- rbind(data[5,],data7)
data <- rbind(data[6,],data8)
data <- rbind(data[7,],data10)
data <- rbind(data[8,],data12)
data <- rbind(data[9,],data13)
data <- rbind(data[10,],data14)
data <- rbind(data[11,],data17)
data <- rbind(data[12,],data19)
data <- rbind(data[13,],data25)
data <- rbind(data[14,],data28)
data <- rbind(data[15,],data29)
data <- rbind(data[16,],data31)
data <- rbind(data[17,],data32)
data <- rbind(data[18,],sw)
```

The problem is that apparently rbind doesn't work for more than 2 rows.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. What are `data2` , `data3`, ...?   BTW, have you considered `t(data)` ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: data2=N2, data3=N3, ... are the columns data sources.

Comment: What does the first data frame have to do with what you're doing with rbind?  Are you also saying you have a ton of dataframes and want to grab their columns and bind them together as rows?  Also `rbind` does work with more than 2 rows: `rbind(mtcars[, 1], mtcars[, 2], mtcars[, 4]) `

Comment: @TylerRinker The data is in the format of first data frame but I have the columns of first data frame in separate tables too.

Comment: are you perhabs looking for a function from the reshape2-package?

Answer (score 0):

possibly your looking for:

```
 library(reshape2)
 melt(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way to do this using reshape, but this is what I can think of at the moment

```
## df is your data frame I am creating a dummy one here...
df <- data.frame(N1 = runif(5), N2 = runif(5), N3 = runif(5), N4 = runif(5))

## then we create a list of single column data frames...
dfList <- lapply(1:ncol(df), function(x) data.frame(col = df[[x]]))

## then we bind them all using do.call and rbind
df <- do.call(rbind, dfList)
```